# Cakephp Model ignores condition in belongsTo

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have 2 Models that are joined but not thrue the id's but with another field.

```
class Post extends AppModel{
    public $useDbConfig = 'test';
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public $belongsTo= array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array('User.field = Post.field')
    ));
}
```

But the cakephp is not connecting the 2 models correctly. To every Post it just gives the the first user (User with id 1). When I check the SQL-Statements the User statement is following:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`group_id`... FROM `users` AS `User` WHERE 1 = 1
```

Any ideas why this is not working?
I also tried joining the models manually:

```
$this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => '15',
        'joins' => array(
            'INNER JOIN users User ON (User.field = Post.field)' 
        ) 
    );

    $posts= $this->paginate('Post');
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I totally forgot to mention that these 2 tables are in different databases. Maybe there is the problem. But I had no problem joining tables over different databases so far.

**EDIT**

I was wrong about the join so I changed it from "belongsTo" to "hasOne" since a post can only be written by one user. But still no changes.

Comment: can u show the models you want to join ?

Comment: The post model is displayed above. What would you need the User model for? I did not change the User model.

Comment: Show the `find` statement. What is the problem with the SQL statement you have shown?

Comment: The find statement ist the paginate just above. The statement isn't joining the tables nor has one of the "field"-values in the where statement.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version! It's working fine over here with 2.5.4. Also the query looks like one produced from a find call on the `User` model, not on the `Post` model!?

Comment: Oh right i forgot. I'm using version 2.5.1! Yeah that's what is bothering me too.

Comment: Just tried version 2.5.4 still no changes. Then I copied the tables into 1 database but still the same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution although I don't understand why the others won't work. I put

```
$this->Post->primaryKey = 'field';
```

right before

```
$posts= $this->paginate('Post');
```

and now it works. Can anyone tell me why the other ways won't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `foreignKey` parameter to any field, not necessarily the `id`:

**Post** model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'some_user_field'
    )
);
```

**User** model:

```
public $hasMany = array (
    'Post' => array (
        'className' => 'Post',
        'foreignKey' => 'some_user_field',
        'dependent' => true
    )
);
```

According to the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html):

> It is not mandatory to follow CakePHP conventions. You can easily
>   override the use of any foreignKey in your associations definitions.
>   Nevertheless, sticking to conventions will make your code less
>   repetitive and easier to read and maintain.

Otherwise, make `joins` manually:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => '15',
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'users',
            'alias' => 'User',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array('User.field = Post.field')
        )
    ) 
);
```

Comment: No sadly cakephp is not that open. Foreign key means that that the id of the other table will be joined with the current's table foreign key.

Comment: Ok, I understand now is that you are not using foreign key, so I made this reference initially. Anyway, I put a suggestion for parameter `joins`.

Comment: Nope it's not working. If I print out the data it only shows the Post-data but nothing about the user.